# Why am I getting "this method should not be called on the main thread" warning?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm getting warnings from Xcode: "This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness", but this is in the App itself (ie, the generated code):

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The warning points at the line with "@main", and I get the warning 4 times.

Of course, when I create a brand new project, I don't get the warning, and the generated code looks identical.

The project I do get the warning on is an old project that I haven't done anything with for several months, so just trying to get everything fired up again. The app runs fine in the simulator (at least basic poking around), but just wondering. I'm sure Xcode version changed, iOS version changed, etc. So what might I be missing?

Thx.

Comment: This isn't actually happening on this part of the app - rather, this means you are likely calling something that generates this warning somewhere else. Do you have any code where you are making requests, doing async things, etc? Also, from [Apple's Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712074?page=5): "When you receive one of these runtime performance issues, you can expand the backtrace in the Issue Navigator, available through the View > Navigators > Issues menu."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, because of the comment by @Mr Developer, I looked at the apple forum thread that talked about viewing the stack traces. The traces were NOT helpful at all, it was just boilerplate code.

What was helpful is one poster there mentioned AdMob. I am using AdMob so I commented that out and sure enough that took care of the warnings. I then found this:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/QQLDBQlO340?pli=1

Bottom line, this warning could happen for any number of reasons, but the code that gets highlighted in Xcode is just the wrong thing to do. That's an apple bug imho.